# Python: Error when running Python script on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, runtime-error, sensors, gpio

Title: "Error when installing Python package using pip"

Details:

I'm running a Python script on my Raspberry Pi, but I'm getting an error message that I can't seem to resolve. Specifically, I'm trying to read data from a sensor connected to my Pi using the RPi.GPIO library, but I keep getting a "RuntimeError: Please set pin numbering mode using GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) or GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)" error message.

I've tried adding the line "GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)" to my script to set the pin numbering mode, but I'm still getting the same error message. I also tried setting the pin numbering mode to BCM, but that didn't work either.

I was expecting my script to read data from the sensor without any errors, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You have multiple questions there.  Which question are you really asking?

Comment: Self answered question are explicitely allowed on StackOverflow. But the question part is expected to meet the normal rules. Here you have 2 distinct *questions* in the same post and your self answer correctly answers one. You should edit out the first part from here, and ask a new post if you need help on that part.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.